# Creating files through a running program in java

Tags: java, project, directory

I have a button on my game and when the game is running there is a button. I want to know if theres a way to create folders within the projects file stream if the user clicks the button. So to be more precise, what code do I need to create a folder within the project(not locally) ?

Comment: Have you tried Googling this?

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a directory like so:

```
boolean success = new File("../some/path/to/my/directory").mkdirs();
```

The above, will also create the directory ancestry. see [File.mkdirs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29)

Alternatively, you can create the directory (without ancestry) using [File.mkdir()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdir%28%29)